# Assigning a variable value to an attribute in a dynamic html table

Tags: html

I have a very simple question. I am becoming little crazy here. I am creating an html table dynamically.I want to set an attribute value for `<input>` tag inside a `<td>`.
For example:
Below is my `<td>`:

```
<td class="sorting_1"><input dummy="111"></td>
```

Now I want to set the dummy attribute value using a variable. i.e. I have the dummy attribute value stored in a variable like below:

```
var dummyVar=111;
```

I want to assign/use the above variable in `<td>` something like below:

```
<td class="sorting_1"><input dummy=dummyVar></td>
```

how can I do that?

I am creating the dynamic table in the flowing way:

```
var issueTableId = "issuetable_"+formattedCKEY;
    var $issuetable = $("
    <table  id='" + issueTableId + "' class='stripe nowrap'  style='position:relative; top:0px; width:95%;'></table>
    ");
    $issuetable.append('
    <thead>
       ').children('thead')
       .append('
       <tr />
          ').children('tr')
          .append('
          <th nowrap>Select</th>
          '+
          '
          <th nowrap>Priority</th>
          ' +
          '
          <th nowrap>Issue ID</th>
          ' +
          var $tbody = $issuetable.append('
    <tbody />
       ').children('tbody');
       $.each(cases, function () {
       $tbody.append('
       <tr />
          ').children('tr:last')
          .append('
          <td nowrap><input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;</td>
          ')
          .append('
          <td nowrap>' + $(this).find("PRTY").text() + '</td>
          ')
          .append(sourceRow)
          .append('
          <td nowrap>' + $(this).find("ISSUEID").text() + '</td>
          ');
          });
```

Comment: use data attribute. I assume that when you speak about var you refer to javascript var

Comment: By using javascript. Have a look at this [mdn link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Comment: @LelioFaieta How to use that please?

Comment: @Lewis I am creating the table dynamically. is there any way to set it while creating the table itself?

Comment: You say that you are creating this HTML table dynamically, can you share the code?

Comment: Dynamic means using what? Javascript? Jquery or any else technology please specify so every can understand and give them best answer

Comment: I have added the dynamic table creation code to the question.Please take a look.

Comment: Use `data` attribute for that and you can access through jquery.

Comment: @CoolJK Any code please?

Comment: Just add `data-id=111` in input tag and access throgh jquery

Comment: @ Cool JK I am confused. Could you please share the complete code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.I can do something like this :

```
'<td nowrap><input type="checkbox" align="center" style="cursor: hand" name="selectIssue" dummy='+dummyVar+'>&nbsp;</td>'
```